# Combination hibernate @Transactional & ehcache @Cacheable always creates DB transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, annotations, ehcache

While doing loadtesting on our application I noticed that if you use @Transactional and @Cacheable annotions that hibernate always creates a database transaction. Is there an easy way to prevent this? 
A more eleberate way to solve this within spring is to have following class/interfaces

- Servicelayer-interface
- Cacheable annotated class which is just a proxy/forward to
- Transactional annotation implentation class

**What happens is the following**

Call 1:

1. Transaction gets created
2. class method gets called
3. result cached & returned

Call 2:

1. Transaction gets created
2. Cached result gets returned

**The prefered result should be:**

Call 1:

1. Transaction gets created
2. class method gets called
3. result cached & returned

Call 2:

1. Cached result gets returned

Comment: it isn't Hibernate that is creating the connection, it's Spring that does so prior to the method invocation that you have marked @Transactional

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to change relative order of `@Transactional` and `@Cacheable` aspects.

It can be configured using `order` attribute of `<tx:annotation-driven>` and `<cache:annotation-driven>`. See [8.2.4.7 Advice ordering](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering) for the meaning of order values.